# Git doesn't detect file changes on Windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10

I am aware this is not a new question, but I had tried many suggested methods from previous posts without any luck, except with this command.

```
git update-index --really-refresh
```

But then, I have to keep using the same command to track every change. Something is broken somewhere and I hope someone can help me troubleshoot. I am running Win10 and `git version 2.28.0.windows.1`

#### Here are the steps to reproduce the problem on my windows command prompt (`cmd`)

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ echo 123 >> text.txt
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commmit -m 'init'

$ git log
commit 1eaa480bf3de4129f76688e0d177b55fe13c4aae (HEAD -> master)
Date:   Wed Sep 23 16:47:23 2020 -0700
    'init'

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

#### Ok so far so good, now let's change the file a little bit

```
$ echo 456 >> text.txt  # append new content into file
$ type text.txt         # to confirm the file has new content
123
456

$ git diff text.txt     # return blank, meaning it couldn't detect new changes
$ git status            # same here, it couldn't detect new changes
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

#### So the above steps had confirmed that my Git couldn't detect file changes. Next, let's see if it can detect **new** file...

```
$ echo 123 >> text2.txt   # create a new file
$ git status              # ok... it can still detect new file
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        text2.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

$ git add .
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   text2.txt
```

#### So it can detect new file, but cannot detect changes on existing file.

- My `.gitconfig` looks like this

```
[core]
  editor = subl -n -w
  preloadindex = true
  fscache = true
  ignoreStat = true
  autocrlf = true
```

So far I have tried:

- Uninstall Git from the control panel, and make sure it's registry also get removed, and then reinstall the latest Git.
- repeat the step on Windows Terminals, PowerShell and Git Bash

But none of them work. What else can I do, any suggestion?

#### Final Update:

The `core.ignoreStat` was the root cause. Changing it to the following fixed my problem. Thanks for folks at https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows. Cheers!!

```
[core]
  ...
  ignoreStat = false
  ...
```

Comment: For this kind of thing, you want to find the group that's actively working on your particular Git-for-Windows version and work with those guys. That means looking at the Git mailing lists. I don't know who is doing which things on Windows, though.

Comment: hmm... since you mention about Windows, let me test with Win10's WSL2 then... oh wow, WSL2 works fine. like you said, it's Git + Window related problem...

Comment: For me this occurred suddenly, when it first was working normally. Only a reboot of my machine fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone from https://groups.google.com/g/git-for-windows had suggested me to remove
`core.ignoreStat` in the gitconfig

Now my git is working normally again. Thanks!

From the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreStat):

> core.ignoreStat
>
> If true, Git will avoid using lstat() calls to detect if files have changed by setting the "assume-unchanged" bit for those tracked
> files which it has updated identically in both the index and working
> tree.
>
> **When files are modified outside of Git, the user will need to stage the modified files explicitly (e.g. see Examples section in
> git-update-index[1]). Git will not normally detect changes to those
> files.**
>
> **This is useful on systems where lstat() calls are very slow, such as CIFS/Microsoft Windows.**
>
> False by default.